# Querying data from last 30 days and 24 hours from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently storing data in postgreSQL that is being displayed back to the user in a chart based on last 24 hours, 30 days and 3 months.

To get the last 24 hours worth of data, I just run the following code when the user requests for it:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    page_visits
WHERE   page_id = '1111'
AND created_at >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
```

I run a cron job every night to aggregate data for that day and store it in a different table (table_day), which only contains aggregated data.

So when the user requests for the last 30 days worth of data, I can run a code similar to the one above to get this month's data. However, it does not include today's data as it is not aggregated and stored in table_day.

So how can I run a query that gets the last 1 month worth of data from table page_visits and aggregated 24 hour data from table_day?

Or is this approach of storing data of different intervals completely wrong?

I intend to do something similar for monthly data, where a cron job runs at the end of every month to aggregate that month's data and stores it in table_month.

And the same question repeats with how I can query data from last last month and last month from table_month and aggregate this month's data from table_day in a single query.

#### page_visits

| id | page_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 2021-12-02T04:55:26.779Z |
| 2 | 1442 | 2021-12-02T02:25:32.219Z |
| 3 | 1111 | 2021-12-02T04:55:26.214Z |

#### Table_day

| id | page_id | visit_count | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 2001 | 2021-13-02T04:55:26.779Z |
| 2 | 1442 | 103 | 2021-13-02T02:25:32.219Z |
| 3 | 1111 | 4024 | 2021-14-02T04:55:26.214Z |

Comment: table `table_day` ?   Where/How is it defined ? the part "So when the user requests for the last 30 days worth of data, I can run a code similar to the one above to get this month's data. However, it does not include today's data as it is not aggregated and stored in table_day." is complete Spanish to /me, ...... Sorry

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was that a cron job only runs at midnight to aggregate that day's data and stores it in another table (e.g. table_day). So when the user requests for the last 30 days worth of data, it wouldn't include today's data as it is not added to that table yet

Comment: Indeed, and requestion the cronjob to run at 23:59 will include today's data, but at the time the user does tak a look at the data it is stil yesterdays data .... So, what do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

If you aggregate the data in the `table_day` table every end of day, then you can use these aggregate data to calculate the monthly's data and store them in the `table_month` table, and then you cas reuse the monthly's data to calculate the quarter's data and store them in the `table_quarter` table.

Every end of day :

```
INSERT INTO table_day
SELECT page_id, extract('day' from NOW()) AS day, count(*) AS count
  FROM page_visits
 WHERE created_at >= extract('day' from NOW())
 GROUP BY page_id
```

Every end of calendar month :

```
INSERT INTO table_month
SELECT page_id, extract('month' from NOW()) AS month, count(*) AS count
  FROM table_day
 WHERE day >= extract('month' from NOW())
 GROUP BY page_id
```

Every end of calendar quarter:

```
INSERT INTO table_quarter
SELECT page_id, extract('year' from NOW()) || '-' || extract('quarter' from NOW()) AS qurter, count(*) AS count
  FROM table_month
 WHERE month >= extract('month' from NOW()) - interval '2 months'
 GROUP BY page_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This inserts the data into those tables but how I retrieve it? When I request for the last 30 days worth of data from table_day, it'll not give me the data for today, since it has not been aggregated and store into that table. Instead I'd have to get it from page_visits. So how would one get that information in one query?